# Trying to insert a row using stored procedured with a parameter binded to an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, asp.net-3.5

Environment:
asp.net 3.5 (C# and VB) , Ms-sql server 2005 express

Tables

Table:tableUser
ID (primary key)
username

Table:userSchedule
ID (primary key)
thecreator (foreign key = tableUser.ID)
other fields

I have created a procedure that accepts a parameter username and gets the userid and inserts a row in Table:userSchedule

Problem:
Using stored procedure with datalist control to only fetch data from the database by passing the current username using statement below works fine

```
protected void SqlDataSourceGetUserID_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters["@CurrentUserName"].Value = Context.User.Identity.Name; 
    }
```

But while inserting using DetailsView it shows error

```
Procedure or function OASNewSchedule has too many arguments specified.
```

I did use

```
protected void SqlDataSourceCreateNewSchedule_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters["@CreatedBy"].Value = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
```

DetailsView properties:
autogen fields: off,
default mode: insert,
it shows all the fields that may not be expected by the procedure like ID (primary key) not required in procedure and CreatedBy (user id ) field .

So I tried removing the 2 fields from detailsview and shows error

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedBy', table 'D:\OAS\OAS\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF.dbo.OASTest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.
```

For some reason parameters value is not being set.

Can anybody bother to understand this and help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my mistake, I didn't know how delegation works and what it was.
Instead of SqlDataSourceCreateNewSchedule_Selecting(....) I should have used SqlDataSourceCreateNewSchedule_Inserting to modify the parameter after all the need was to set parameter while inserting not selecting.